# Weird shadow at object intersection in render view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh

[image: ** I Don´t know exactly what is happening, but when I intersect two meshes this strange shadow appears and I can´t find the way to take it out**]
I Don´t know exactly what is happening, but when I intersect two meshes this strange shadow appears and I can´t find the way to take it out

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a shadow but like a Freestyle Stroke.

Make sure you have that unchecked in your render settings:

[image: demo pic]